# Get most recent state from series of transactions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am searching in the dark here. I am not even sure if what I am ideating actually exists.

I have a transaction based database which contains a series of updates to records. Each row contains updates to one or more columns. Is there a way to get the final state of the entire record. For example:

```
+-----------+---------+---------+--------+---------+
| update_id | country | status  | amount | device  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--------+---------+
|         1 | UK      | valid   |    100 | iPhone  |
|         2 |         | invalid |        |         |
|         3 |         |         |    200 | Android |
|         4 | DE      |         |    300 |         |
|         5 |         | valid   |        | Android |
|         6 |         |         |     50 |         |
|         7 | FR      |         |    350 |         |
|         8 |         |         |        | iPhone  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--------+---------+
```

The final state here is:

```
FR | valid | 350 | iPhone
```

Is there a way I can get that (but for millions of unique records and hundreds of columns) in one query or other method?

At the moment the only way I can think of is using a cursor and updating a final state table, but that takes ages.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2016, but could upgrade to 2017.

Answer (score 1):

You can use subqueries, but you have to write a single subquery for each column:

```
declare @tmp table (update_id int, 
     country varchar(2), 
     status varchar(10), 
     amount int, 
     device varchar(20))

insert into @tmp values
 (1 , 'UK'    , 'valid'   ,    100 , 'iPhone' )
,(2 , null    , 'invalid' ,   null ,  null    )
,(3 , null    , null      ,    200 , 'Android')
,(4 , 'DE'    , null      ,    300 , null     )
,(5 , null    , 'valid'   ,   null , 'Android')
,(6 , null    , null      ,     50 , null     )
,(7 , 'FR'    , null      ,    350 , null     )
,(8 , null    , null      ,   null , 'iPhone' )

select 
(select top 1  country from @tmp where country is not null order by update_id desc) as country,
(select top 1  status  from @tmp where status  is not null order by update_id desc) as status,
(select top 1  amount  from @tmp where amount  is not null order by update_id desc) as amount,
(select top 1  device  from @tmp where device  is not null order by update_id desc) as device
```

Result:

[image]

Otherwise you can generate a dynamical TSQL statement with all the columns from SQL Server metadata.

Comment: Thank you that works. Is there code which would do the same, but grouping by another column such as account_id. I would then get the final state for each account...